# Screen one shader onto another?

Tags: shaders

I have two shaders. One with highlights and one without. Is there any way to make the highlight layer pure black and white, then screen (blending mode) that onto the other shader so that I only get the white portion of the shader.

I've tried several methods, but have failed. I want to make sure the hilight shader is pure black and white too, because otherwise, when I boost the environment color it polutes the shadows.

Here are my two shaders I wanna use:

[image]

[image]

I know I could accomplish this with render layers, but I'd like to solve it all in one material if possible.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the answer through trial and error, here was my solution:[image]